# C++ template usage problems pointers

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
class Form { ... }

Form<MainWindow*> form;
```

T will become T*

Is there a way to use ::staticMetaObject somehow from T thats T* now? I want keep this part `Form<MainWindow*> form;` like it is

thank your for helping me

**edit**

as wanted in the comments i provide some code.

```
class FormBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FormBase() {}
};

template <typename T>
class Form : public FormBase, public QList<T>
{
public:
    Form(T a)
    {
        QList<T>::append(a);
    }

    T operator<<(const T t)
    {
        QList<T>::append(t);
        qDebug() << T::staticMetaObject.className();
    }
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    form = new Form<MainWindow*>(this);
    *form << this;
}
```

as pointed out T becomes T* and thats why T::staticMetaObject is not working. Of course i want to let the template like it is like that Form, cause it should be clear that there are pointers in the list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did edit my question

Comment: @Invader Why don't you use `T*` in the `Form` class in 1st place, and simply write `form = new Form<MainWindow>(this);`?

Comment: cause it should be clear that pointers are stored in the list when declaring new. it would be really confusing if i write it like u suggest

Comment: @Invader Well, then treat `T` as it's always a pointer in `Form` (use `->` and `*` to dereference).

Comment: can you give me an example how the staticMetaObject works then, how does it look like?

Comment: @Invader [`std::remove_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) could be helpful for doing that.

Comment: Could you just dereference: `form = new Form<MainWindow&>(*this); *form << *this;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `std::remove_pointer` template:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class Form {
public:

    int give_me_staticMetaObject()
    {
        typedef typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type obj_type;

        return obj_type::staticMetaObject;
    }
};


class Foo {

public:

    static int staticMetaObject;
};

int Foo::staticMetaObject=5;

int main()
{
    Form<Foo *> f;

    std::cout << f.give_me_staticMetaObject() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU remove_pointer works